# search between 2 dates without the year

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to search between two dates without the year 
i mean to serach between all the specific dates with same month 
i tried:
select amount from sly where date between #01/01/yyyy# and #31/01/yyyy#

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO. Seems like you try to find results for date=January, any year

Here the query "yyyy" won't work.

Try to read over [these date examples](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762) then try something like

```
select amount from sly where month([date]) =1
```

be careful about using column names with generic names as 'date', it might be a reserved word.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks it really helped me